How do I create a multiline equation with one braces which is part of a bigger equation?
How do I create a multiline equation with tall curly braces in Tex? split causes the braces to be split in two lines which is not something I want. See the pictures below to understand the problem.
This is what I want:

This is what I am getting:

Ignore the part inside the bracket. It's just something I populated to fill the space.

Welcome to TeX,SE! Please show us the code, which you try to write so far.

As starting point may serve this:
\documentclass[margin=3mm, preview]{article}

\begin{document}
    \[
\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\int\limits_{s_1}^{s_2}\int\limits_{-\frac{h}{2}}^{\frac{h}{2}}
    \rho(x)\left\{\begin{array}{l}
                            u_i\delta u_i + v_i\delta v_i + ... \\
                            + x + y + w
                          \end{array}\right\}(\sin\alpha + z)\,dz\,du\,ds
     \]
\end{document}

where correct math terms I left to write to you.


I suggest you place an aligned environment inside a pair of \left\{ and \right\} directives -- or, for better horizontal spacing, \mleft\{ and \mright\} directives. And I'd also indent the second row a bit, to make it obvious it's a continuation of the first row.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for 'aligned' environment
\usepackage{mleftright} % for '\mleft' and '\mright' macros
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}   % Times Roman text and math fonts
\newcommand\dd[2]{#1_t\delta #2_t} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\[
\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \!
\int\limits_{s_1}^{s_2} \!
\int\limits_{-h/2}^{h/2} \!
\rho
\mleft\{
  \begin{aligned}
    &\dd{u}{u}+\dd{v}{v}+\dd{w}{w}
       +z^2\bigl(\dd{\phi}{\phi}+\dd{\psi}{\psi}\bigr) \\
    &\quad+z\bigl(\dd{u}{\phi}+\dd{\phi}{u}+\dd{v}{\psi}+\dd{\psi}{v}\bigr)
  \end{aligned}
\mright\}
(\sin\alpha + z)\,dz\,ds\,d\theta 
\]

\end{document}

